# Create an associated model from JSON

Tags: ember.js, associations

I have a server response that looks like:

```
comments: [
  0: {
    body: "test3",
    created_at: "2013-06-27T22:27:47Z",
    user: {
        email: "test@test.com",
        id: 1,
        name: "Tester"
    }
  }
]
```

And ember models:

```
App.Comment = DS.Model.extend({
  user: DS.belongsTo('App.User'),
  body: DS.attr('string')
});

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

How do I create an ember user model from the server's response?

Comment: Are you using ember-data or are you looking for a vanilla example without any persistence library?

Comment: I am using ember-data and rails. I figured out the solution and will post it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution if you're using rails active model serializers is to `embed :ids, include: true`:

app/serializers/comment_serializer.rb

```
class CommentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  embed :ids, include: true
  attributes :created_at, :body
  has_one :user
end
```

Just like [the readme for active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) says, this will produce:

```
{
   "users":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"Tester",
         "email":"test@test.com",
      }
   ],
   "comments":[
      {
         "event":"commented",
         "created_at":"2013-06-27T22:27:47Z",
         "body":"test3",
         "user_id":1
      }
   ]
}
```